# router setup with server checking MAC addresses

Tags: router, mac-address

I am running my own router on my university's network. The university checks to make sure the mac address of the computer is registered before allowing traffic to go through. What I've done is setup the router to use my computer's MAC address. The main reason I am running a router is to allow access to my wireless printer and to my mythTV web interface for me and my roommates. However, since everyone is connecting through the router, the network traffic is significantly slower (I'm pretty sure the university does some type of throttling).

Is there anyway to set up my router to allow the university network to see all the computers (and thus throttle on a per computer basis), but then hide the printer to only people on my router's network?

Thanks so much for your help,
Patrick

Answer (score 2):

Don't connect everyone else through your router. Let them connect through their regular university account/access. Make your router publish your printer on a specific port at your IP. Then only you will be behind the router (same with MythTV interface if needed.) Only the people who know your IP will be able to use the printer. You can also set up your computer to be a print server if you are concerned about restricting access further, and don't publish the printer itself on the router.

Answer (score 2):

Also remember that your set up is probably against the ToS you signed to get the connection.

Anyone who isn't you should not be going through your router, when they torrent movies it's all against your name.